# Making a view Controller stay active (in Background)

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiviewcontroller

I've got a view Controller which manages my TV Playout (HDMI Apple AV Adapter). Everything works fine. I call my view Controller using a popover on the iPad.

When I open the popover, the external screen is recognized and I can work with it. But when I close the popover View (which means I send my TV Playout View Controller to the background) the TV screen (logically) turns black.

Is there a possibility to tell my view Controller to hold the picture on the TV screen by quit?

Like "pseudocode"

```
[TVOutViewController stayActiveInBackground]; //pseudocode
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, By chance, I found a solution (or at least a workaround). Be sure to manage the problem using a UISplitViewController with your TVOutViewController as the masterViewController and the ContentViewController as the detailViewController. Apple already did the work. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've coded your view controller so it explicitly shuts down the external `UIScreen`/`UIWindow` pair when it becomes inactive. I suggest you move the external screen code out of your popup's view controller and into an object which has a lifetime independent of what's going on on the internal screen, e.g. your application delegate or an object referenced by it. Then just send that object messages from your popup view controller in response to user events.

There's nothing about the Apple APIs that causes this kind of behaviour - it's purely a consequence of how you've designed your app. As such I don't recommend trying to force the view controller to stick around. Instead, try to find a better structure for the app. A view controller should only be responsible for its view, not application state.